# Paramiko fails connecting /w "Private key file is encrypted" when upgrading to 2.9.0+

Tags: python, paramiko, ssh-keys

The following works fine using paramiko 2.8.1, but fails with any 2.9.0+:

```py
    pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(pkey_str)

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, port=int(port), username=username, pkey=pkey) # paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
    return ssh.open_sftp()
```

Same SFTP host, same user, same key, etc. I've looked at [paramiko's changelog for 2.9.0](https://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html#2.9.0), which says:

> Specifically, you need to specify `disabled_algorithms={'keys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']}` in either `SSHClient` or `Transport`.

But that doesn't change anything:

```py
    # still: paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
    key_cfg = {'keys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']}
    ssh.connect(host, port=int(port), username=username, pkey=pkey, disabled_algorithms=key_cfg)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the workaround to fall back to `ssh-rsa`:

```py
    fallback_to_sha1 = {'disabled_algorithms': {'pubkeys': ['rsa-sha2-256', 'rsa-sha2-512']}}
    ssh.connect(host, port=int(port), username=username, pkey=pkey, **fallback_to_sha1)
```

The workaround comes from a [post in Paramiko issues](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/1643#issuecomment-1120234137), which suggests that Paramiko's changelog docs are slightly wrong.

I found https://ikarus.sg/rsa-is-not-dead/ has a good explanation of what's going on. In short, `ssh-rsa` implies using SHA-1 for message signing, but [only SHA-1 is being phased out](https://csrc.nist.gov/News/2022/nist-transitioning-away-from-sha-1-for-all-apps). To avoid forcing everybody to regenerate RSA keys ("RSA is not dead"), a new RFC 8332 `server-sig-algs` protocol defines how servers & clients can agree on the signature algorithm to use.

According to that article, the host I'm connecting to doesn't yet fully support that protocol:

```bash
❯ ssh -i REDACTED.id_rsa -l REDACTED -p REDACTED -o "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -vvv REDACTED.com 2>&1 | grep rsa-sha2-512
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
```

There's no `kex_input_ext_info`, whereas GitHub:

```bash
❯ ssh -vvv git@github.com 2>&1 | grep rsa-sha2-256
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
```

IMO since this was introduced in a minor version, paramiko should've implemented an automatic graceful fallback to `ssh-rsa`, reserving the "fail if server doesn't support `server-sig-algs`" behavior for a major version.